# Value is never used in function(JS)

Tags: javascript

I have function for filtering results

Here is code

```
filtered = markers.filter(function (marker) {
                var getDate = marker.date.match(/\d/g).join('');
                var markerDate = new Date(parseFloat(getDate));
                return (markerDate => valDateStart && markerDate <= valDateEnd && (marker.imei === imei || imei === null));
        });
```

It was refactored from this

```
  $.each(markers, function (i,marker) {
                var getDate = marker.date.match(/\d/g).join('');
                var markerDate = new Date(parseFloat(getDate));
               // var valDate = new Date(startValue[2], startValue[1] - 1, startValue[0]);
                if (markerDate => valDateStart && markerDate <= valDateEnd && (marker.imei === imei || imei === null)) {
                    filtered.push(marker);
                } 
            });
```

But now in this row `var markerDate = new Date(parseFloat(getDate));` I have `markerDate is never used`

Where is problem?

Comment: Maybe try `markerDate >= valDateStart` in that third line.

Comment: Replace `=>` with `>=`

Comment: TBH the old code had exactly the same problem

Comment: Yes. You're right.Thank's @Andy

Comment: `markerDate => ...` shadows / redefines `var markerDate = new Date(parseFloat(getDate));`

Comment: How it can redefine or shadow, if I just using marker date in return that define above?@AlexKudryashev

Comment: [It is not using the date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) ...